# Difference between "types" and "path" triple-slash directives in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

In the [Triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) section of the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/) It says:

> Similar to a `/// <reference path="..." />` directive, which serves as a declaration of dependency, a `/// <reference types="..." />` directive declares a dependency on a package.

Will somebody please explain the key distinction in more detail? Im new to TypeScript and confused after reading the documentation!

Comment: `path` takes an absolute or relative file path, including file extension, while `types` is resolved using the rules for looking up type definitions. For example, compare `path="./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts"` and `types="jquery"` the latter of which by default resolves to `./node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts`

Comment: @Aluan Haddad ! Thank you so much bro ^^

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.